# Json via java. need send Special symbols

Tags: javascript, java, json, parsing, formatting

I would like send json like `{"str" : "string1"}` where string1 I take from db and it can be like :

```
" ; "msisdn"= 380<!^d+${9}>
мин/макс - 1//4999
номер для теста - 38091

"
```

& of course I got an error:

```
{"errorMessages":["Illegal unquoted character
```

How i can fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can encode your specific data with [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)

Comment: SO is an english only platform. If you rather use Russian, please use [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Ivar, sorry, i fixed my answer